# Why does "Bitmap.SaveToFile results black screens

Tags: delphi, canvas, bitmap

L.S.,

Using Delphi (Seattle) I have successfully created a drawing within a FireMonkey application. I did this through using statements like

```
path.MoveTo( PointF(X1,Y1));  
path.lineto( PointF(X2,Y2));  path.AddEllipse(RectF(ILeft,ITop,IRight,Ibottom));  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;  
Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.StrokeThickness := 1;  
Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.StrokeDash := TStrokeDash(0);
Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawPath(path, CoI.X*2); 
Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene; 

etcetera..(lots of them)
```

The final drawing appears perfect on my screen, but when I want to save the bitmap, and I open the file thereafter, it always appears to be a black screen! Why so?

I used the statement :

```
Image1.Bitmap.SaveToFile('AFilename.bmp');
```

Can anybody please tell me what I need to do to get it right? 
Many thanks ahead.

Jan

Comment: I remember such an issue, unfortunately I do not remember what solved it.

Comment: Aren't they PNG in fmx

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `TBitmap` in FMX supports several formats, including BMP, JPG, and PNG. [Supported Image Formats](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmapCodecManager#Supported_Image_Formats)

Comment: @JGMS: which platform(s) are you running your app on?  BMP is only supported on Windows and OSX. Like David said, you should probably be using PNG instead.

Comment: I am running my app on Windows 7 and 10. So BMP should be OK. JPG would suit me too.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  path: TPathData;
begin
  path := TPathData.Create;
  path.MoveTo( PointF(10,10));
  path.lineto( PointF(20,20));
  path.AddEllipse(RectF(15,10,25,30));

  Image1.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create(50, 50);
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Clear(TAlphaColors.White);
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.StrokeThickness := 1;
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawPath(path, 1);
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;

  Image1.Bitmap.SaveToFile('C:\Users\me\Desktop\AFilename.png');
end;
```

[Output AFilename.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDPMr.png)

Comment: Thank you Stefan. I added the color definition as in your example and used the png extension as well. Now it works. Great!